# UIViewController pushViewController high retain count of View controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, retaincount

I wrote the following piece of code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc]initWithLevelNumber:([levelGroup intValue]*100+indexPath.row) Bonus:NO];

NSLog(@"Retain Counter =%d",gameViewController.retainCount);

[navController pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];
[gameViewController release];

NSLog(@"Retain Counter=%d",gameViewController.retainCount);

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

The results of the two logs are, in sequence **1** and **6**!
How this is possible? I only call the alloc method one time and release after push the controller on the stack.. alloc-> +1, push-> +1, release-> -1 = 1 or not?

I'd like the view controller is dealloc'd when i pop it off the stack..

Comment: try to change it to autorelease and see what happens

Comment: Don't use `retainCount` to check for leaks. Use the instruments tool. Search SO for 'retaincount', you'll find many, many reasons why it's a terrible property 99% of the time. It's just not worth the hassle for the 1% of the time it's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autorelease your GameController creation, like this:

```
GameViewController *gameViewController = [[[GameViewController alloc]initWithLevelNumber:([levelGroup intValue]*100+indexPath.row) Bonus:NO] autorelease];
```

Then delete `[gameViewController release]`; Then your code looks kosher, and `gameViewController` will be autoreleased after being popped from the nav stack. Don't worry about `retainCount` - when you push a view controller, `UIKit` takes over and will `retain`/`release` the thing as needed. You just have to worry about your code. Actually, the way you have it written should be fine, I just think my suggestions here make the code cleaner.

Unless you see in Instruments that you have a memory leak of your `gameViewController` object, I think you needn't worry.

Answer (score 6):

Please read this note to be clear in this question. It is part of **NSObject Protocol Reference**:

**Important:** This method is typically of no value in debugging memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects ***may have retained an object*** in order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, ***it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method***.

[NSObject Protocol Reference. RetainCount discussion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount)

Comment: I wish more people would up-vote this. `retainCount` is a useless property, and should never have been in the public SDK.

Comment: That's not correct - it's useless in situations where the OP is trying to debug a complex memory graph, however `retainCount` is extremely useful in a more controlled environment, such as an internal framework where you know exactly what you're doing and have absolute control over object allocation, retention and release.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is some retain internally (by pushViewController: method), you should not check the retain count, only check that you release the object you own, especially when you check retain count between sdk call methods.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use NSNotificationCenter in your GameViewController?
May be you add your view controller as observer to NotificationCenter and it increase retainCount.